# Android mime messages to send email

Tags: android, email, smtp, mime, mime-message

Currently I have and Android app that uses the API javax.mail to send emails. I want do the same thing with an another API more lightweight than it. I am trying to do that using the org.apache.commons.net SMTPClient and I have achieved send simple text emails. The problem is that I don't know how to add and attachment to the email. The solution seems to be create manually the MIME messages. 
Does exist any Android lightweight API to build mime messages than can be send using SMPT?

Thanks

Comment: Has a google search turned up anything?

Comment: Nothing interesting. All the Mime classes are inside javax.mail API